# How to launch activity from background app above 26 API?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to open my activity from service or broadcast when my app is in background.

I have tried following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

It is working fine on bellow Android 26 APIs. But for above 26Api it is not launching activity.

It is giving flowing info in android LogCat

```
Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request
```

Answer (score 3):

Android 10 has increased restrictions on "starting new activities from the background". Checkout the documention: [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions)

For more detailed information regarding why these restrictions are imposed, check out this keynote from Chet Haase. [GFM2019-Keynote-Chet Haase](https://youtu.be/zLMszotGOHs?t=294)

Comment: Thats is true. But how whatsapp call is working. I need such functionality for my app.

Comment: @RahulGiradkar When app receives a system broadcast where the app is expected to launch a UI. Examples include ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and SECRET_CODE_ACTION. The app can start activities for a few seconds after the broadcast is sent. So whatsapp might be using some intent listeners like that to start activity from background.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```